# como remapear efectivamente teclas Home y Control linux mint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vscode, linux-mint, archlinux

Amigos, estoy intentando remapear las teclas Alt=Control y Home=Alt. he intentado con estos comandos:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 110 = Alt_L"
xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = Control_L"
```

tambien he intentado editando el archivo  /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc y nada.

Vscode cuando presiono alt me muestra "control+alt" y cuando presiono home "alt+home". si presiono control+alt+t no abre la terminal. Es decir, queda con dos asignaciones la tecla.

En fin, estoy usando linuxMint 21. En windows es muy facil pero aqui esta dando la pelea.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

nota: por alguna razon las dos teclas control no funcionan en el teclado por eso necesito reasignarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos pues lo solucione yo mismo con esta aplicacion **xkeycaps**.(si no se encuentra instalarla). Ella nos permite hacer un cambio de tecla "exchange keys" dando clic derecho e intercambiando las funciones de las teclas.

muy importante que no queden dos teclas realizando la misma funcion porque no funcionara!!!. Luego darle clic en "write output" para crear un archivo que haga el cambio permanente. al final puede crear un archivo sh con este contenido

```
 xmodmap ~/.xmodmap-`uname -n`
```

le da permisos de ejecucion y busca en aplicaciones de inicio para ejecutarlo al iniciar sesion. Por favor colocal un retraso de 1 minuto(sleep 1 en el sh si no da opcion de retraso).

Listo amigos con esto el cambio de tecla sera efectivo y podran incluso usarlo en combinacion de teclas. Espero que pueda ayudar a alguien.

Comment: como hago para que me queden lo cambios? no se mucho de linux